# Helpful recommended closure flag, post not closed?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, closed-questions, helpful-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023193/templatesyntaxerror-expected-token-got-social) post for recommended closure because it's caused by a typo. My flag was marked as helpful, but the post is still open. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your flag put the question into [the close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26743849). There, a user with close vote privileges saw it, agreed that it needed to be closed, and cast a close vote of their own.

That automatically marked your "recommend closure" flag as helpful, because a user with close vote privileges agreed that the question needed to be closed.

However, it takes 3 close votes to get a question closed (unless it's a moderator who casts one of the votes, then it's immediately binding), so the question has not yet reached enough votes to be closed.

Getting the question closed is not the metric for having a "recommend closure" flag counted as helpful. All that is required is someone with [close vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) agreeing with you.