# Prevent flags from being marked helpful by your own close votes

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close

I had flagged a question as duplicate before reaching 3k (the question itself isn't relevant here) and later came to it and close voted it. That marked my original recommend closure flag on the same question as helpful. ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399669/helpful-recommended-closure-flag-post-not-closed))

This seems to allow for some potential abuse. Someone could flag a bunch of borderline questions, get to the close votes privilege, and then cast close votes on all the posts to farm helpful flags count. Should letting you close vote all the previous questions you've flagged to make them helpful be allowed?

Comment: The potential for abuse seems extremely limited here. Also, the worst case is that the user gets an increased helfpul flag count, which doesn't matter for anything (i.e. there are no privileges associated with that number).

Comment: Is that really THAT big of an abuse vector? 1. It needs a fair bit of planning. 2. You'd get, what? Maybe 50 flags marked helpful at most? I'm not sure if there is a max amount of flags that can be pending but that would be the potential "abuse". And that's per account. Unless you also plan on reducing your rep and then repeat but if you want to go through all that effort, I'd say sure. Waste your time. It's not really hurting anything.

Comment: @cigien Not entirely true. Helpful flags increase the number of flags you can cast per day. (See the last bullet [on this privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).)

Comment: @Ivar Yes, that's technically true. But a user who's reached (or close to reaching) the CV privilege has likely maxed out their daily flag limit already. There are also much easier ways to get the maximum possible daily flags, than the approach described in this question.

Comment: @Ivar well yes - you get more flags to cast but...if you use them to cast flags that you mark helpful yourself, is it THAT big of a deal? Also, there is an easier way to get helpful flags - by flagging non-borderline questions. And comments. And there is enough of these to go around.

Answer (score 9):

This was actually [an intentional change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting), the reasoning being

> this new *close* privilege supersedes the old and you should be able to exercise that privilege.